# How to check if something already exists in a text file

Tags: c#

Code snippet below

```
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new                  

    System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt", true))
    {
    file.WriteLine();
    }

    int userType = 0;
    tring retrievedUsername = String.Empty;

using (System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt"))
{
    retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
}
```

With edits to the above code, how can I check if something already exists in a text file? Or return a true or false bool. That way I can check if a certain string matches text in a text file, not just contain it. ( MSDN Is a big pain to read.... Half of it I have no understanding of )
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean check something already exists? Be more specific. Do you want a method to return `true` depending on whether a particular string is found or not?

Comment: What do you mean "if something exists"? Is there text in it? Or if it contains a certain string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to look if a username is already in a line of a file, you can use `File.ReadLines` + `Contains`, for example

```
bool containsUser = File.ReadLines(path).Contains(username);
```

Comment: I want to see if a username already exists in the file Usernames

Comment: @mechron: so every username has its own line?

Comment: Yes, is there a problem?

Comment: @mechron: i have edited my answer to replace `"Hello World"` with `username`. Does that help?

Comment: By the way, I have to put system.io in front of everything related to files, pathing, ect. Is there an easier way for this? Thanks in advance! Edit:Edited the question so you can see the full code

Comment: @mechron: add this  at the top of the file: `using System.IO;`

Comment: Nvm, sorry for troubling you. Fixed it with some tinkering, thanks to everyone and you!

Answer (score 0):

retrievedUserName.Contains(thingYouAreCheckingFor) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string s2 = "fox";
    bool b;
    b = s1.Contains(s2);
    Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
    }
}
```